# RavenDB searching multiple words

Tags: c#, .net, search, cloud, ravendb

I want to search documents in RavenDB and make the search results more precise for each word searched.

This is my current code (simplified). For each iteration in the loop I want to make and "and" clause. How is that possible?

At the moment I just get more results for each word, but I want to get less results per word.

```
using (var session = this.ravenSession.Store.OpenAsyncSession())
{
    var query = session.Query<TestDocument, TestIndex>();

    foreach (string word in search.Split(' '))
    {
        query = query.Search(x => x.Brand, word, boost: 5)
                     .Search(x => x.Model, word, boost: 3)
                     .Search(x => x.Variant, word)
                     .Search(x => x.Color, word);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out this query demo https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/queries/filtering-results-multiple-conditions

Comment: Also, see this code in the tests https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/64a0adcea676a27dfb903b21797b1e4d97f1a47a/test/SlowTests/Issues/RavenDB_5669.cs#L45

Comment: Also, see this documentation https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.1/Csharp/indexes/querying/filtering#where

Answer (score 4):

**Solved**: I had to use a DocumentQuery and make sub clauses for each loop.

```
using (var session = this.ravenSession.Store.OpenAsyncSession())
{
    var query = session.Advanced.AsyncDocumentQuery<TestDocument>();

    var words = search.Split(' ');

    for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
    {
        query.OpenSubclause();

        query = query.Search(x => x.Brand, words[i]).Boost(5).OrElse()
                     .Search(x => x.Model, words[i]).Boost(3).OrElse()
                     .Search(x => x.Variant, words[i]).OrElse()
                     .Search(x => x.Color, words[i]);

        query.CloseSubclause();

        if (i < (words.Length - 1))
        {
            query.AndAlso();
        }
    }
}
```